# VBA move data from one range to another sheet range based on matching values in reference cell

Tags: excel, vba

On sheet 1 I have a value in A1, I have a table in A5:A11,B5:B11.

A5:A11 are headers that match sheet2 B1:G1. A:A is the list of matching values for A1.

B5:B11 are values I want moved to sheet2 into their columns with headers that match A5:A11 in the row on sheet2 that has the value from A1 in its column A:A.

Here is some previously suggested code to do it, however it is not functional but I think its close to working.

```
Sub moveData()
    Dim rS As Range
    Dim rT As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    With Sheet1
        lRow = .Range("a1").Value
        Set rS = .Range("A5", .Cells(.Rows.CountLarge, 1).End(xlUp)) 'source headings
    End With
    With Sheet2
        Set rT = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'target headings
    End With

    'find matching heading Sheet2, copy data to specified row
    On Error Resume Next 'skip over non-matches
    For Each Cel In rS
        Sheet2.Cells(lRow, rT(Application.Match(Cel.Value, rT, 0)).Column).Value = Cel.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Can the value in 'Sheet1' cell A1 ever have more than one match in 'Sheet2' column A?

Comment: hmmm, yes it is possible there could be a duplicate. If the function would overwrite both or pick the first in the list that would work.

Comment: When I run the macro it does not error out, it just does not do anything. I've tried looking at the variables in the watch window however I cant see the ranges its finding or watch the final calculation step for what cell location to use. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim VisCell As Range
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Intersect(ws2.UsedRange, ws2.Columns("A"))
        .AutoFilter 1, ws1.Range("A1").Text
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each VisCell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
            ws1.Range("B5:B11").Copy
            VisCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Next VisCell
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: your code copied and transposed the data onto sheet2 however the headers in column 1 are dynamic and change order etc so a copy and transpose of the data to the row wont work correctly. It has to find the matching headers from sh1 A5:A11 in sh2 B1:G1, then locate the correct row via matching sh1 A1 to sh2 A:A and paste the value in the intersect of that column and row. I appreciate your time and energy!

Comment: I believe what I need to do is take the below code
`For Each VisCell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
            ws1.Range("B6:B11").Copy
            VisCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Next VisCell`

and change it from copy/paste the transposed range B6:B11 in offset 1 to copy/paste it in the intersect of [sh1.("A6:A11"):sh2.("B1:G1")]:[(sh1.("A1"):sh2:("A:A")]

Comment: In excel i can use the index match to return the value of the cell I wish to paste the data into. Is there a way for me to replicate this function in VBA to find the correct cell location to paste my data?
`=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:G3,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A2:A3,0),MATCH(Table1[[#This Row],[Column1]],Sheet2!B1:G1,0))`

Comment: Here is where I am at currently

I can find the location of the header from A6 and value in A1 on sheet 2. What I'm not sure how to do now is tell it to copy/paste the data from B6 into the intersect cell of the value from A1's row and the column from Header 1.